# Нужно обернуть скрипт node.js в функцию для вызова по кнопке

Tags: javascript, node.js

при попытке обернуть этот код в функцию без параметров на выходе ошибка "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("ping 127.0.0.1", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: А где находится эта кнопка?

Comment: Потому require() не существует в браузерном JavaScript.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/4711135

Comment: button на html, вызов функции будет осуществляться через  onclick="function()"

Comment: это не браузерный js. Сборка десктоп приложки на node.js через фреймворк electron js

Comment: спасибо, в вашей ссылке нашел решение вопроса. В index.js электрона в функции создания окна дописывается 

        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // Create a new window
    addItemWindown = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        title: 'Add Item',

        // The lines below solved the issue
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
```